# geom_polygon wrapping on y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been trying to plot the result of normalmixEM using the method described by jlhoward found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25313578/any-suggestions-for-how-i-can-plot-mixem-type-data-using-ggplot2). My problem is that my dataset comes right off the y-axis, leading to a result that looks like this:

[image]

I can't figure out how to keep geom_polygon from wrapping like that when it runs into the y-axis.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: An easy work around is to expand the plot limits with `+ xlim(-100, 1000)`. However, your data seems to bump up against zero and therefore may not fit a normal distribution very well.

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't solve the problem. It does extend the axis, but the polygons don't extend into the expanded space still.