# Using user-defined functions within "curve" function in R graphics

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, user-defined-functions

I am needing to produce normally distributed density plots with different total areas (summing to 1). Using the following function, I can specify the lambda - which gives the relative area:

```
sdnorm <-  function(x, mean=0, sd=1, lambda=1){lambda*dnorm(x, mean=mean, sd=sd)}
```

I then want to plot up the function using different parameters. Using ggplot2, this code works:

```
require(ggplot2)
qplot(x, geom="blank") + stat_function(fun=sdnorm,args=list(mean=8,sd=2,lambda=0.7)) +
  stat_function(fun=sdnorm,args=list(mean=18,sd=4,lambda=0.30))
```

[image]

but I really want to do this in base R graphics, for which I think I need to use the "curve" function. However, I am struggling to get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the help file for `? curve`, you'll see that the first argument can be a number of different things:

> The name of a function, or a call or an expression written as a function of x which will evaluate to an object of the same length as x.

This means you can specify the first argument as either a function name or an expression, so you could just do:

```
curve(sdnorm)
```

to get a plot of the function with its default arguments. Otherwise, to recreate your ggplot2 representation you would want to do:

```
curve(sdnorm(x, mean=8,sd=2,lambda=0.7), from = 0, to = 30)
curve(sdnorm(x, mean=18,sd=4,lambda=0.30), add = TRUE)
```

The result:

[image: curve]

Comment: Ah! I now see what I was doing wrong - I didn't specify the "from" and the "to" arguments for the curve function. The default display is from 0 to 1.  Well done - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following in base R

```
x <- seq(0, 50, 1)
plot(x, sdnorm(x, mean = 8, sd = 2, lambda = 0.7), type = 'l', ylab = 'y')
lines(x, sdnorm(x, mean = 18, sd = 4, lambda = 0.30))
```

**EDIT** I added `ylab = 'y'` and updated the picture to have the y-axis re-labeled.

[image]

This should get you started.

Comment: Well done - thanks! I hadn't thought of first defining x as a sequence and then obtaining values.