# ggplot fitted distributions aren't quite level with the x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to model output data from the "mixtools" package in a similar manner to how [jhoward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2985007/jlhoward) did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25313578/any-suggestions-for-how-i-can-plot-mixem-type-data-using-ggplot2) with minor changes.  The examples provided work as expected and his solution works with my data, however the fitted distributions seem...tilted.

[image: Here is a link to my output graph.]

Notice how both distributions are angled above the x axis slightly.

Using an artificial dataset doesn't show the problem anymore.

```
`sample.ratio`=c(rnorm(120000,0.386,0.0842),rnorm(200000,0.653,0.1153))
`mixmdl_k2.sample`=normalmixEM(`sample.ratio`, k=2)

ggplot_mixEM <- function(EM) {
  require(ggplot2)
  x       <- with(EM,seq(min(x),max(x),len=1000))
  pars    <- with(EM,data.frame(comp=colnames(posterior), mu, sigma,lambda))
  em.df   <- data.frame(x=rep(x,each=nrow(pars)),pars)
  em.df$y <- with(em.df,lambda*dnorm(x,mean=mu,sd=sigma))
  ggplot(data.frame(x=EM$x),aes(x,y=..density..)) + 
    geom_histogram(fill=NA,color="black")+
    geom_polygon(data=em.df,aes(x,y,fill=comp),color="grey50", alpha=0.5)+
    scale_fill_discrete("Component\nModes",labels=format(em.df$mu,digits=3))+
    geom_density(color="red",linetype="dotted")
}
ggplot_mixEM(`mixmdl_k2.sample`)
```

[image: The distribution plots are new level].  The distribution fills are now level, though they are also no longer constrained to the (0,1) interval.

About my data: it ranges explicitly from 0-1, and the bimodal distribution modeled by mixtools is expected.  Increasing the x scale with `scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-0.1,1.1))` didn't solve the issue.  The first solution from the link above, provided by [Spacedman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/211116/spacedman), also worked on my data, but gave the same "tilted plot" results.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix this tilt? Is there a way to force extend the shading to the x axis?

Thank you.

Edit: added in sample code.

Comment: You should include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) here in the question with sample input data and the code you used to make the plot.

Comment: I added in a sample of my code, but the problem doesn't show up anymore with an artificial dataset.

Comment: Well it would be useful to determine how your data is different from simulated data. Right now you seem to be calculating the polygon only over the range of `x` but the distribution may not be 0 at the extremes. Probably best to extent the range over which you calculate values. Also, where did you pick up the odd habit of quoting variable names in backticks?

Comment: The backticking is due to the fact that most of my data has numbers in their names (as you see in a second), and RStudio doesn't like it when a number is the first character in a variable.  I've been trying to not start variables with numbers recently, but I digress...

I'm not sure how the sample and real datasets could be different.
``> head(`sample.ratio`)
[1] 0.4416384 0.4001051 0.5458209 0.2530325 0.4094072 0.3403063
> head(`20-03_UG.Ratio`)
[1] 0.6800000 0.2826087 0.6153846 0.3333333 0.4137931 0.3333333``


What step should be modified to extend the calculation range?

Comment: Turns out it was the `x       <- with(EM,seq(min(x),max(x),len=1000))` line. I changed it to max(1.1) and it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the line

`x       <- with(EM,seq(min(x),max(x),len=1000))`

to

```
x       <- with(EM,seq(min(x),max(1.1),len=1000))
```

Seems to have fixed it.